# Given an $n\times n$ table whose rows are distinct, how to delete a column such that the rows remain distinct?

Tags: combinatorics

> Given an $n$ by $n$ table ($n>1$) where the rows are pairwise distinct. Show that one can delete a column such that in the remaining table, the rows are still pairwise distinct.

This question looks very simple, but I do not know how to construct a formal proof.

My vague idea is to delete the column which has the most repeated entries.

Is there any connection to point topology?

Comment: "My vague idea is to delete the column which has the most repeated entries." -- What if they have equally many? For instance,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\text{ or }
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I believe this question is related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bondy%27s_theorem#:~:text=4%20Notes-,Statement,%E2%88%A9%20S%20are%20all%20distinct.

Comment: @maomao, are the entries of your table equal to either $0$ or $1,$ or do they belong to an arbitrary set?

Comment: @AnneBauval I think we can assume that they are just 0-1 entries, although there is no such restriction in the problem formulation.

Comment: Do you mean that your more general problem reduces to Bondy's problem (linked above by Umesh)? If so, how?

Comment: @AnneBauval, sorry for the confusion, I mean we can start with the 0-1 case; somehow I believe (no formal proof) that this simpler case demonstrates the essence of the question.

Comment: Your post is still unclear to me. Are you asking for a proof of Bondy's theorem, or for a derivation of your more general conjecture from that theorem? These are two distinct questions, which should belong to distinct posts.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether OP has followed the link given by @Umesh and whether OP understands the theorem of Bondy given at that link.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957487/colored-grid-with-no-repeated-rows-problem is worth a look, especially the answer posted to it. I only skimmed it, but I formed the impression that the argument given there may apply to the general case.

Comment: This answers your question (whatever it is, cf. previous repeated question in comments above, which your comment just after this one still does not answer): [Why does Bondy's Theorem work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490605/why-does-bondys-theorem-work)

Comment: To clarify, I was not aware of Bondy's theorem, which was only mentioned by Umesh in his comment.

Comment: @GerryMyerson AnneBauval Many thanks for the reference. I will study them shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Nice problem! Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that by removing any column, we will end up with two equal rows. Therefore, note that by removing a column $C$, if the lines $\ell_A$ and $\ell_B$ become equal, they differ in precisely one entry (that entry being the index of the column).

Consider a graph, where each vertex represents a line in our table. For each column $C$ draw an edge between some two lines $\ell_A$ and $\ell_B$ which become equal after removing $C$ (if there are several such pairs of lines, pick one arbitrarily). Hence, our graph has $n$ vertices and as per our assumption, we will draw $n$ edges.

Therefore, there exists a cycle in our graph, say $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ldots,\ell_k$. Let's start walking along the edges of the cycle, starting in $\ell_1$. Each edge denotes a change in an entry and no two edges change the same entry, as every edge comes from the removal of a different column.

Once we have finished our walk, we have performed changes to $k$ different entries of $\ell_1$, yet we end up with $\ell_1$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, our assumption is wrong and we can indeed remove some column $C$ which will leave us with distinct lines.

**Remark.** We cannot guarantee that two distinct columns with this property exist. Consider, for instance, the table filled with $1$'s under the main diagonal and with $0$'s in the other entries, as seen below for $n=4$: \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \color{red}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \color{red}1 & \color{red}1 & 0 & 0 \\ \color{red}1 & \color{red}1 & \color{red}1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} In this case, the only satisfactory column is the last one. The motivation behind this construtcion is that $G$ is a spanning tree, more specifically a path of length $n-1$: $$\ell_1\sim\ell_2\sim\cdots\sim\ell_n.$$

Comment: Hi ovlad, 1) I am not sure but I believe that your answer is the same as the accepted one in the duplicate (mentionned above).  If so, you can delete it. 2) If you think it is not the same, it should be posted over there (rather than here).

Comment: My bad, it's the same answer, I didn't see the linked post. I won't delete it though, for the sake of the remark.

Comment: The remark could be a comment, but where? below the accepted answer of the duplicate?